# Por que só estou a receber a primeira palavra do campo da base de dados?

Tags: php

O código a baixo retorna valores da base de dados, porém o campo `model` so me retorna a primeira palavra do campo da tabela, o resto do nome do modelo não aparece. O que estarei a fazer de errado?

```
<?php
include('conecta.php');

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$sql = "SELECT product_id, model, price FROM ocqp_product LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {



        echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="pid" value='. $row["product_id"].' ><br>
        <input type="text" name="model" value='. $row['model'].' ><br>
        <input type="text" name="price" value='. $row["price"].' ><br>


        </form>';
   }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Estrutura

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXgcR.png

Comment: Todos os names nos inputs são repetidos, não sei se isto tem haver. Posta a estrutura da tabela

Comment: Já alterei os names, não tinha reparado ainda obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: *** Posta a estrutura da tabela [2]

Comment: posta 1 ou 2 linhas do conteudo do banco, talvez ajuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim, você não estava colocando aspas no `value`.

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="pid" value="'. $row["product_id"].'" ><br>
        <input type="text" name="model" value="'. $row['model'].'" ><br>
        <input type="text" name="price" value="'. $row["price"].'" ><br>


        </form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

O Augusto está correto adiciono ainda

```
echo '<input type="" name="" value="'.$row['name'].'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que você mistura os métodos do Mysqli, recomendo usar o modo Orientado a objetos, no caso seu código ficaria assim:

```
   <?php
include('conecta.php');

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$sql = "SELECT product_id, model, price FROM ocqp_product LIMIT 5";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($conn->num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $conn->fetch_assoc($result)) {



        echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="pid" value="'. $row["product_id"].'" ><br>
        <input type="text" name="model" value="'. $row['model'].'" ><br>
        <input type="text" name="price" value="'. $row["price"].'" ><br>


        </form>';
   }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

É, e você esqueceu das aspas no value!